# How to Open Internet settings programmatically in ios?

Tags: ios, settings

I have a radio streaming application. In the splash screen I want to check whether the internet connection is available or not. If not available have to redirect to wifi or 3g settings. How to open this settings programmatically within my application.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability use this

Comment: yes I can check the reachability,, but I need to know how to open wifi or 3G settings of the device programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it is **not possible** to open default **setting page**.

It is possible in-case if the device is Jail Broken.

Till now **Apple** not providing the any **URL Schema** for achieving this one in newer versions.

like `URL Schema`(upto ios5.0 work.it is working after that this one depreciated. )

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```